# Where to put custom widget file?

Tags: widgets

I've created a new widget based on one of my parent theme's custom widgets. In the parent theme the widget files are in the `/inc` and `template-parts` folders. I created these same folders in my child theme but can't get the widget to show up on the widgets page. However, it works if I add the widget code to the `functions.php` file.

**UPDATE:**

Now I have another problem: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action()`

This is the code I'm using to register the widget:

```
// Register the widget
function myplugin_register_widgets() {     
register_widget( 'Home_Categories' ); 
} 
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myplugin_register_widgets' );
```

This is how the original widget is registered:

```
// Register the widget

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'return register_widget("Codilight_Widget_Block1");'));
```

Comment: sorry, but "I have a bug in my code" without showing the code is just a poor question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created a custom widget, created a file by example `class.my-widget.php` containing the class definition of the custom widget, something like this:

```
class my_widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        //logic here
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        //logic here
    }

    public function form($instance) {
        //logic here
    }

    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        //logic here
    }

}
//registering my widget so its available in the back-end
add_action('widgets_init', function() {
    register_widget('my_widget');
});
```

and the file its inside a folder in your theme like this:

[image]

you have to load that file, to do that you have to add this to your `functions.php`:

```
//lets define a constant for the URL to your theme folder
define('YOUR_THEME_FOLDER_PATH', trailingslashit(get_template_directory(__FILE__)));
//lets load the custom widget
require_once (YOUR_THEME_FOLDER_PATH . 'inc/class.my-widget.php');
```

the `inc/` part can be updated to the folder the file is.

Comment: Instead of `define('YOUR_THEME_FOLDER_PATH', trailingslashit(get_template_directory(__FILE__)));` could I use `define('YOUR_THEME_FOLDER_PATH', trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()));`?

Comment: I dont recommend it, that will return the `URL` instead of the `PATH`.

Comment: that cant be `add_action()` its a WordPress core function

Comment: update your question with all this info and how are you calling your widget in functions.php

Comment: I got it to work by changing `get_template_directory(__FILE__)` to `get_stylesheet_directory(__FILE__)`

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to "override" any source file to create your own widgets. The existence of the former widget, assuming it is properly coded, should not be an issue by itself, just adds some clutter to the widgets admin UI.

So just add your own widget, inherit the original widget class if it is helpful, and in case you really don't want the original to stay around, just use the https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget API

Comment: It's actually a new widget with different functionality but based on one of the theme's custom widgets.